# Redux mapDispatchToProps method is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have been trying to find out but dunno what's going on. Even at React Tool, I can see the action is passed but the state is empty (for testing I have put the empty object at default). Action is passed but for some reason, the state is not returning as props. whatever I put at action, it's returning the default one which is empty.

```
//bookReducer
    import { GET_BOOKS } from "../actions/types";
    const initialState = {
      books: [
        { id: 0, name: "Toten Tea", author: "Lonal" },
        { id: 1, name: "Poppy Hill", author: "Leonard" },
        { id: 2, name: "Clause Horse", author: "Henry Nicols" },
      ],
    };
    
    const bookReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      //   console.log(action.type);
      switch (action.type) {
        case GET_BOOKS:
          return {
            ...state,
          };
        default:
          return {};
      }
    };
    
    export default bookReducer;
    
    //Homepage
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import { GET_BOOKS } from "../actions/types";
    
    class Homepage extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatchAction();
      }
      render() {
        const { books } = this.props;
        // console.log(books);
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Hello To Test-Redux Project</h1>
            {books ? (
              books.map((book) => {
                return <li key={book.id}>{book.name}</li>;
              })
            ) : (
              <div>No Entry</div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        books: state.books.books,
      };
    };
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        dispatchAction: () => dispatch({ type: GET_BOOKS }),
      };
    };
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Homepage);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        books: state.books.books,
      };
    };
```

Why  `state.books.books` only `state.books` should do the job.
also `this.props.dispatchAction();` is not changing any state.